# 2d matrix, 2 points given, find third one at a certain distance, PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, geometry, 2d

Good day all.
I'm doing a simple script in PHP, I'm having problems about a simple geometrical problem:
I have a 2d matrix, width=10000 and its height = 6000.

I have 2 points, A(2000,1000) and B(3400,5000).

What I'd like to calculate is a third point, at a distance of 1500 from (let's say) A, on the same line.

I've worked a simple line function:

```
$x1= 2000;
$y1= 1000;
$x2= 3400;
$y2= 5000;

$x = 1500;

function givemeY($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$x){
return ($y2-$y1)/($x2-$x1)*($x-$x1)+$y1;
}
```

but this is working only if I give it at least $x, but, I don't know $x, i'd like only a point 1500 away from, in this case (2000,1000). (I suspect in this example the point will have negative values, it's ok).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know PHP but this should be pretty easy to implement with some pseudo code:

```
function getXComponent(angleOfLine){
    return Math.cos(angleOfLine)*1500;
}
```

and for the y component

```
function getYComponent(angleOfLine){
    return Math.sin(angleOfLine)*1500;
}
```

Now just use the X and y components to place the new point.